# SharePoint API requests failing

Tags: c#, json, httpclient, sharepoint-api

I'm trying to Get all files from a folder on a SharePoint site AND creating folders on said site. So GET/POST.

1. When i'm trying to GET the files from the folder https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/Syra_Test/
   i get a 200 success but nothing in the resulting json.: `"{"odata.metadata":"https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Files12\","value":[]}"` i'm guessing its path issues but i don't know.
   see function1()
2. I am now trying to create folders, however i get a 403 error.
   see function2()

   ```
        private static void Function1(){
            //string RESTURL = "{0}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items?$top=1";
            string RESTURL = "{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/General')/Files";
            string webUrl = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com";
            string USER = "xxxxx@xxxxx.com";
            var passWord = new SecureString();
            string PWD = "xxxxx";
            PWD.ToList().ForEach(passWord.AppendChar);
            var credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(USER, passWord);            
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential })
            {
                //Get authentication cookie
                Uri uri = new Uri(webUrl);
                handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credential.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri));
                //Invoke REST API 
                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(string.Format(RESTURL, webUrl)).Result;
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string jsonData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
        }


    private static void Function2(){            
        string RESTURL = "{0}/_api/web/folders";
        string webUrl = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com";
        string USER = "xxxx@xxxxx.com";
        var passWord = new SecureString();
        string PWD = "xxxxx";
        PWD.ToList().ForEach(passWord.AppendChar);
        var credential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(USER, passWord);
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential })
        {
            //Get authentication cookie
            Uri uri = new Uri(webUrl);
            handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, credential.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri));

            //Invoke REST API 
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();                    
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "POST");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                string json = "{'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': '/shared documents/folderSyraCreated'}";
                StringContent strContent = new StringContent(json);                    
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(string.Format(RESTURL, webUrl), strContent).Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string jsonData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Can't use external dll's (csom) in this case (plugin for an economy system)
Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: Would it not be better to use the `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` package to interact with your SharePoint environment?

Comment: maybe, im new to interaction with sharepoint but ill try to do some research, have some pointers ?

Comment: scratch that, not a possibility as i can't use external dll in this case (plugin for an economy system) forgot.